# What potential alternatives could replace plea bargaining?

Tags: plea

If plea bargaining should be abolished or not is a relatively controversial topic since many consider it unfair. However, since courts are overflowing now, if plea bargaining was abolished it would seem implausible that the current court system would be able to handle the additional roughly 93% of cases. So, are there any practical and realistic replacements for the system if it were to be abolished?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a political question

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting question, especially in light of a decision that you may have already seen from earlier this month, where a federal judge in West Virginia announced he was [no longer accepting plea bargains](https://reason.com/volokh/2018/04/21/district-judge-generally-rejects-plea-ba) as a matter of routine.

There are lots of potential approaches, including:

- Expanding the judiciary;
- Establishing guidelines limiting which
  guidelines prosecutors will pursue;
- Limiting the reach of criminal
  law;
- Rolling back defendants' procedural protections; or
- Setting
  higher standards for arrest or indictment.

I'm sure there are plenty of other options, but this is what pops into my mind at first.